# Drupal Theming Taxonomy Vocab similar to a Node Type

Tags: php, drupal-6, themes, taxonomy

Is it possible to theme a Drupal 6 vocab the same way you would a node type. Having it effect every term within the vocab?

I find drupal 6's taxonomy core is lacking when it comes to theming. I want to build custom charts and user statistics based on my taxonomy terms but I can't get anywhere near it without doing some ugly dance with views.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Arthur

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by 'theme a Drupal 6 vocab', as vocabularies and terms do not get themed. Do you mean to theme nodes differently based on the terms associated with the nodes?

Comment: If my taxonomy vocab is books, you click on "Science Fiction" (Term) You load a page with statistic charts, usage, and categories of "book" nodes that use this term. I don't want to display a randomly assorted list of content sharing that term.

I want to drop custom views, php & java scripts into a .tpl page that takes care of every term within a vocab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using the [Taxonomy Node](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_node) module. It will create a node under a specific node type for each taxonomy term in a selected vocabulary. From there you can add custom content to each taxonomy, like images, videos, views, comments, etc.

Answer (score 1):

D6 theming of taxonomy pages is indeed a little sparse.

However, if you want the power, then 'panels' provides a great 'taxonomy term' context that will override the /taxonomy/term/n URLs and allow you to display the bits you want, such as the term description at the top, then all 'stories' with that term in in a teaser list, and all 'pictures' tagged with that term as a gallery preview, and maybe the older stories in a archive list also.

It takes a little getting used to the terminology and where buttons are in panels, but once you see how context arguments get passed down, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort the page that shows all the nodes using a term, then you can use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).
Template files should not be directly changed, as far as possible. Doing so, you can change the currently set up theme without to copy all the modified template files you created.